# jQuery table navigation using relative selectors only

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Given a table such as the following:

```
  <tbody>
        <%foreach (var book in Model.Books)
          { %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%: book.Title %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= book.AuthorsToLinks("MyBooks/List") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: book.Genre.GenreName %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" value="<%: book.Review.Rating %>" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="bookRating">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= Html.ActionLink("Edit" , "Edit", new {bookID = book.BookID}, new { @class = "editBook"}) %>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <%} %>
    </tbody>
```

How the Sam Hill do I select the hidden input value above the "bookRating" div?

I think I've tried every combination of prev() / parent() / children() / next() , etc., and I'm completely out of patience.

Thanks.

Update:

Here is my JS that isn't working:

```
$('.bookRating').raty({
    start: $(this).parent('td').prev('td').children('input').val(),
    readOnly: true
});
```

I am trying to insert a rating for each row, as you can see.  $(this) is apparently the problem.  Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.bookRating').parent('td').prev('td').children('input').val();
```

Should do.

---

I don't think you can't use `this` in that function to refer to the object that called the function. Given that there might be multiple `.bookRating`, you probably need to iterate through each of them separately (I'm not sure how your plugin works):

```
$('.bookRating').each(function(){
    $(this).raty({
        start: $(this).parent('td').prev('td').children('input').val(),
        readOnly: true
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming what I thought.  I'm going to update my question here in a sec...

Comment: Awesome!  This is the ticket.  The only thing I had to do was assign $(this) to a variable to keep track of the scope.  Thanks Chief.